# Как выводить имя родителя в этой же таблице?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица под названием "products" в ней есть поля id, product_type_id, count_remains, name, parent_id, description, last_delivery_id. Есть отчет

```sql
select * from (
    select dic_product_type.name as type_name,
    products.name         as name,
    products.description,
    products.count_remains,
    (select delivery_date from deliveries
        where deliveries.id = products.last_delivery_id order by id desc
        limit 1) as last_delivery_date
    from products
    left join dic_product_type on products.product_type_id = dic_product_type.id) query
```

Мне нужно получить product.name, id которого указан у другого продукта в столбце "parent_id". Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ещё раз соединить с `products` и выбрать оттуда

```
LEFT JOIN products par_prods
  ON (products.parent_id = par_prods.id)
```

Comment: А что написать в select'е?

Comment: в select'е нужно написать что-то вроде `par_prods.name as parent`